# SharePoint Modern List Disappearing

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I have a brand new Modern list in SharePoint and filled it with a mix of 15 fields. I went to test adding an item and after it submitted, the list view disappears. I'm left with a blanks screen. If I switch it back to Classic mode, I can see the item there. Switching it back takes me to a blank looking screen. I've had multiple users test this with a new list and it's happening to them as well. I'm not receiving reports that they are blanking on production lists.

Anyone ran across this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it in my dev tenant. Do you see any erros in the browser console ?